# Win 7 Format exact partition sizes?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I wanted to create 2 partitions that would show exactly 1TB and exactly 500 GB in windows 7. I partitioned and formatted the drive using win 7 disk manager, using values : 1048576 for 1 tb and 512 000 for 500 GB, however, in My Computer the sizes shown are 0.99 TB and 499 GB. So what are the correct values please ?

To clear things, the drive size is 2 terra, and the goal is to get 3 partitions, and for them to show as exacly 1 TB, 500 GB, and aprox 383 (the third and last) in My Computer.

Thank you!

P.S. I noticed that in the Disk management utility of windows which i used to partition the sizes are shown as 1024 GB and 500 GB, but in My Computer they are shown as 0.99 TB and 499 GB. Cool huh ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a tool like [`Partition Wizard`](http://www.partitionwizard.com/) or [`Gparted`](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/index.php), so you can input the values that you want.

I think you need it in MB, right?  Here are the correct values:

`1 terabytes = 1 048 576 megabytes`

`500 gigabytes = 512 000 megabytes`

I think you are using this values, so verify that you are not mistyping your values.

Comment: That's exactly what I entered and I'm sure I didn't enter it wrong.

Comment: @noru have you tried increasing by 1MB?  So it would be: `1 048 577` and `512 001`?

Comment: That worked, thank you !!! But why ? :)

Answer (score 0):

1 099 511 627 776 bytes = 1TB

536 870 912 000 bytes = 500GB

It usually it's represented like you did, this is the reason why USB has less storage than they said...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using **GParted**, but I tried adding *extra 4 MiB* while partitioning HDD with **[GParted live](http://www.gparted.org/livecd.php)** and it is shown exactly as 100GB (or 200GB, 500 GB,...).

For 100 GB: 102400 MiB + 4 MiB = 102404 MiB => exactly 100GB on Windows

For 500 GB: 5 x 102400 MiB + 4 MiB = 512004 MiB => exactly 500GB on Windows